# Insert values in database after json_encode()

Tags: php

I have two dimensional array, and I got needed result. 
Now I need to insert it into db.

If the situation is [[]], that is one row in db and has specific number in db (it should start with 1).

If the situation is [[] , []], in that case values in brackets are dimension, each bracket is row, but they have the same name, for ex 2.

If there are more brackets inside [[] , [], [], []], in this case we will have 4 rows with the same name.

My database looks like

ID  |  DIMENSIONS  |  NAME

ID - auto increment
DIMENSIONS I take from below.

For ex. 
[[12500,10]] - is one row, and for NAME it will have number 1.
[[12500,8],[6400,2]] - this is six element in array below. It will have two rows in database, and will have NAME 6.

echo json_encode($pak); // produces output below

```
"[[[12500,10]],[[12500,10]],[[12500,10]],[[12500,10]],[[12500,10]],[[12500,8],[6400,2]],[[6400,10]],[[6400,10]],[[6400,10]],[[6400,10]],[[6400,10]],[[6400,10]],[[6400,10]],[[6400,10]],[[6400,10]],[[5558,10]],[[5558,10]],[[5558,8],[4600,2]],[[4600,10]],[[4600,10]],[[4600,10]],[[4600,10]],[[4600,10]],[[4600,10]],[[4600,10]],[[4600,10]],[[4600,10]],[[4600,10]],[[4600,6],[4500,4]],[[4500,10]],[[4500,10]],[[4500,10]],[[4500,10]],[[4500,8]]]"
```

I got stuck here, any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve it by Recursion.

But here I didn't use recursion (Because I am not good at that)

I haven't tested properly, so please go through it carefully. let me know if it has any problem.

```
$data = "[[[12500,1]],[[12500,2]],[[12500,3]],[[12500,4]],[[12500,5]],[[111111,6],[22222,6]],[[6400,7]],[[6400,8]],[[6400,9]],[[6400,10]],[[6400,10]],[[6400,10]],[[6400,10]],[[6400,10]],[[6400,10]],[[5558,10]],[[5558,10]],[[5558,8],[4600,2]],[[4600,10]],[[4600,10]],[[4600,10]],[[4600,10]],[[4600,10]],[[4600,10]],[[4600,10]],[[4600,10]],[[4600,10]],[[4600,10]],[[4600,6],[4500,4]],[[4500,10]],[[4500,10]],[[4500,10]],[[4500,10]],[[4500,8]]]";
$decoded = json_decode($data);
$namedArray = fix_name($decoded);
$insertArray = arrange_array($namedArray);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($insertArray);
echo "</pre>";die;

// Fix the Name first
function fix_name($decoded)
{
$number = 1;
foreach ($decoded as $key=> $value) {
    $value['name'] = $number;
    $insertArray[] = $value;
    $number++;
}
return $insertArray;
}
function arrange_array($namedArray)
{
    $insertArray = [];
  foreach ($namedArray as $array) {
    if (count($array) > 2) {
        $name = $array['name'];
        unset($array['name']);
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            $array[$key]['name'] = $name;
        }
        foreach ($array as $arr) {
            $insertArray[] = arrange($arr);
        }
    } else {
        $temp['DIMENSIONS '] = $array[0];
        $temp['NAME'] = $array['name'];
        $insertArray[] = $temp;
    }
    }
   return $insertArray;
}
 function arrange($array)
{
    $temp = [];
    $temp['DIMENSIONS'] = [$array[0], $array[1]];
    $temp['NAME'] = $array['name'];
    return $temp;
}
```

Process:

First: Fix the names

Next: If count > 2 (because "name" key was added in previous function so will have minimum two )

then array in different way

else

key 0 as DIMENSIONS  and key name as NAME

NOTE: There are other ways to achieve it but for quick fix I gave this.